# How to use array_filter in Node.js

Tags: php, node.js

I am facing small issue on array_filter. I have successfully used it on PHP but now i want to change this on nodejs.
Any help will be thankful for me.

## MyPHPScript

```
$targets = [1.2, 2.3, 3.5];
$live_coin_price = 1.3;

$targets_hit = array_filter($targets, function($target_value) use($live_coin_price){
            if($live_coin_price >= $target_value)
            return $target_value ;
        });
```

It will check if $target_filter > 0 or not .
This is workable code on PHP.

## NodeJs

I tried similar with nodejs. but its not working what needs to be change.
Its a socket call on Web socket of Binance. I want to create an socket by using my data .

```
const app       =     require("express");
const mysql     =     require("mysql");
const http      =     require('http').Server(app);
const io        =     require("socket.io")(http);
const WebSocket = require("ws");


var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "cryptobot"
  });

var coinName = "";




con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT tr.id, tr.title, tr.coin, tr.exchange, tr.reason, tr.buy_zone, tr.stop_loss, tr.status, tr.created_on as trade_creation_date, max(case when target_number = '1'  then target_value end) AS target1,    max(case when target_number = '1'  then target_created_on end) AS target1_created_on, max(case when target_number = '1'  then target_updated_on end) AS target1_updated_on, max(case when target_number = '2'  then target_value end) AS target2, max(case when target_number = '2'  then target_created_on end) AS target2_created_on, max(case when target_number = '2'  then target_updated_on end) AS target2_updated_on, max(case when target_number = '3' then target_value end) AS target3, max(case when target_number = '3' then target_created_on end) AS target3_created_on, max(case when target_number = '3' then target_updated_on end) AS target3_updated_on, max(case when target_number = '4'  then target_value end) AS target4, max(case when target_number = '4'  then target_created_on end) AS target4_created_on, max(case when target_number = '4'  then target_updated_on end) AS target4_updated_on, max(case when target_number = '5' then target_value end) AS target5, max(case when target_number = '5' then target_created_on end) AS target5_created_on, max(case when target_number = '5' then target_updated_on end) AS target5_updated_on FROM trades as tr inner join trades_target as tt on tr.id=tt.trades_id where status =1 GROUP BY tt.trades_id", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var results = result;

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var row = results[i];
            coinName = row.coin;
        var stopLoss = row.stop_loss;
        var buyZone = row.buy_zone;

        var targetCreatedOn = [row.target1_created_on, row.target2_created_on, row.target3_created_on, row.target4_created_on, row.target5_created_on];
        var targetUpdatedOn = [row.target1_updated_on, row.target2_updated_on, row.target3_updated_on, row.target4_updated_on, row.target5_updated_on];

        var targets = [row.target1, row.target2, row.target3, row.target4, row.target5];

        const binanceWS = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/"+coinName+"@kline_1m");

        var websocketList = [];

        binanceWS.on("open", function open() {
            console.log("open action");
        });

        binanceWS.on("message", function incoming(data) {
            var datas = JSON.parse((data));
            var liveCoinPrice = datas.k.c;
            var liveCoinHighPrice = datas.k.h;
            var liveCoinLowPrice = datas.k.l;

            // send data to every websocket client
            websocketList.forEach(ws => {
                ws.send(data);
                
            });

            var filteredArray = targets.filter((value, index, array)=>{
                if(liveCoinPrice >= targetValue){
                    return targetValue;
                }
                
            });

            function targetValue(el){
                return liveCoinPrice;
            }
            console.log(targetValue);
        });
       
      }

    });

});


const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8081 });

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {

    // add ws handle to websocket list.
    websocketList.push(ws);

    ws.on("close", function close() {
        console.log("Disconnected");
    });
});
```

Now I want to change this with nodejs . How can i do it?

Comment: Please let me know why this question is down voted? So that i can change my question accordingly.

Comment: Not me. But I think you should also include what you have tried in js :)

Comment: I will add and edit it.

Comment: @Eddie edited please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter` in javascript is [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

On your code, `targetValue` does not exist. The variable used on the function parameter is called `value`

**Note:** Both `array_filter` and `filter` callback function expects a `bool` return value. Not the value itself.

```js
let targets = [1.2, 2.3, 3.5];
let liveCoinPrice = 1.3;

let targets_hit = targets.filter(function(target_value) {
  return liveCoinPrice >= target_value;
});

console.log(targets_hit);
```

...Or you can make it shorter using js arrow function:

```
let targets_hit = targets.filter(o => liveCoinPrice >=  o);
```

Comment: What do you mean? @TanmoySarkar

Comment: foreach ($targets_hit as $key => $target){

}.
how can i change this one.

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Actually you can only ask one problem or question per post. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174511/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-eddie).

Comment: @Edddie need help

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can only ask one problem or question per post. I quite sure I already answered this post. :)